# How to add progress bar on ViewPager for every pager

Tags: android

I want to implement one code where I need to add progress bar on `ViewPager`, for every pager progress bar will show until image will not load. for more details you can check this link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440254/how-to-fetch-images-on-viewpager-from-server/46461109#46461109)
There is a `ViewPager` where images is coming from server side which takes time to load I want to add progress bar until image will not load

This is layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="1dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/loader_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="8dip"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:max="100">
</ProgressBar>
```

```
public class SlidingImage_Adapter extends PagerAdapter {
private ArrayList<String> IMAGES;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;
ProgressBar progressBar;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public SlidingImage_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> IMAGES) {
    this.context = context;
    this.IMAGES=IMAGES;
    for(int i=0;i<IMAGES.size();i++)
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
  //  ImageView imageLayout = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_slide_fragment, view, false);
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_slide_fragment, view, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    Log.e("instantiateItem: ",IMAGES.get(position) );
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(IMAGES.get(position))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loader_image)
            .into(imageView);

    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return IMAGES.size();
}


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);

}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState(){
    return null;
   }
 }
```

thank you

Comment: you can achieve using  glide @Vikas Godiyal

Comment: What do you mean by using glide?

Comment: In ViewPager by default besides page load at same time so when you swipe to next you would not able to see progress bar

Answer (score 1):

Use Picasso to load the image that comes with loader settings

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .fit()
        .error(R.drawable.error_drawable)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.loader_image)
        .into(imageView);
```

**screen_slide_fragment.xml should contain only ImageView as the rootView.** This is how your method would look like

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
    ImageView imageLayout = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_slide_fragment, view, false);

    Picasso.with(context)
        .load(IMAGES.get(position))
        .placeholder(R.drawable.loader_image)
        .into(imageLayout);

    return imageLayout;
}
```

Add this in your app's gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: It is compulsory to use Picasso

Comment: There is another alternative which is Glide

Comment: What should I have to use in place of network ImageView

Comment: @Vikas Godiyal Use normal image view

Comment: Okey I have changed Network Image View to simple ImageView but there is one error on imageView.setImageUrl(IMAGES.get(position), imageLoader); (Can't resolve method)

Comment: Use the `load(imageUrl)` to set the image URL

Comment: Where will I put the load function?

Comment: That's your loader drawable... Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4454450/4620609 for that

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView error

Comment: I should used Network Image View because the images will come from server

Comment: Picasso will take care of the network image that's why you're specifying the url in load method. In your screen_slide_fragment.xml just push the image view as the root view delete everything else.... that should solve the classcast exception problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155482/discussion-between-vikas-godiyal-and-samuel-robert).

Comment: Please check the edited code where images is not coming

Comment: I have posted layout file please check it.

Comment: Add fit() method to the picasso

Comment: placeholder method is not working while I put another image on it it's working properly